# Checkbox selection not working in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

**HTML**

```
<form role="form" ng-submit="addStore(store)" name="AddStoreForm" novalidate>
    <label>Store Category</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"  ng-repeat="store_category in store_cat">
            <input type="checkbox" name="store_category" ng-model="store.store_category">{{store_category.name}}
        </label>
    </label>
 </form>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary campwidth">SUBMIT</button>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.store_cat = [
    { name: 'A', selected: false },
    { name: 'B', selected: false },
    { name: 'C', selected: false }
];
$scope.addStore = function(store){
    console.log("responsestore", store);
    alert(store.store_category);
};
```

Here I put store category as array. After submit the form. I got alertbox category undefined. I want to sent the result using API.  how to fix this problem. [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/xOOwIK1lDB0feO1CFyUL?p=preview)

Comment: can you explain how your example should work? what should happen and when clicking on what?

Answer (score 2):

It will work with button tag not with form as in bootstrap `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary campwidth" ng-click="addStore(store_cat)">SUBMIT</button>` here no need of using the form tag b'coz it may leads to conflict in angular.js so, it will work definately for checkbox.
http://plnkr.co/edit/qSFnxTNZ4n63pw3JXZA5?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can, do something like that:     `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary campwidth" ng-click="addStore(store_cat)">SUBMIT</button> here`
http://plnkr.co/edit/KtBzqeMF9FZt6bnI0MBF?p=preview
You shouldn't use form and take on that function nope, that way is wrong when you use angular.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your issue is with data format not being pushed into a new `store` object, here is a solution for that:

```
<form role="form" name="AddStoreForm" novalidate ng-init="store={}">
  <label>Store Category</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="store_category in store_cat">
    <input type="checkbox" name="store_category" ng-init="store[$index]={name: store_category.name, selected: false}" ng-model="store[$index].selected">{{store_category.name}}
  </label>
  </label>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="addStore(store)"  class="btn btn-primary campwidth">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

And the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qSFnxTNZ4n63pw3JXZA5?p=preview) with working example.